# R add index column to data frame based on row values

Tags: r, indexing

This is a continuation of [r - How to add row index to a data frame, based on combination of factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092239/r-how-to-add-row-index-to-a-data-frame-based-on-combination-of-factors)

I tried to replicate what I believe to be the desired results using the green checked answer and am consistently getting something other than expected.  I am sure I am doing something really basic wrong, but can't seem to see it OR I've misunderstood what the desired state is.

The data from the original post:

```
temp <- data.frame(
Dim1 = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B"),
Dim2 = c(100,100,100,100,200,200,100,200),
 Value = sample(1:10, 8)
 )
```

Then I ran the following code:  `temp$indexLength <- ave( 1:nrow(temp), temp$Dim1, factor( temp$Dim2), FUN=function(x) 1:length(x) )`

and:  `temp$indexSeqAlong <- ave( 1:nrow(temp), temp$Dim1, factor( temp$Dim2), FUN=seq_along )`

and then I created the following:  `temp$indexDesired <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)`

...ending up with the data frame below:

```
  Dim1 Dim2 Value indexLength indexSeqAlong indexDesired
1    A  100     6           1             1            1
2    A  100     2           2             2            1
3    A  100     9           3             3            1
4    A  100     8           4             4            1
5    A  200    10           1             1            2
6    A  200     4           2             2            2
7    B  100     3           1             1            3
8    B  200     5           1             1            4
```

If I can figure out what I'm not getting the desired index -- and assuming the code is extensible to more than 2 variables -- I should be all set.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the last value in `indexDesired` shouldn't be `4`?

Comment: @thelatemail  I am sure it SHOULD be! Thanks for the catch

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat  I'd be happy to share a small snippet of data that shows the respective results of the 2 approaches proposed below.  However, I can't seem to find any direction on how to properly enter data into SO questions and am making lots of extra work for the mods.  When I figure that out, I'll put the comparison up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `data.table`, there is a "symbol"  `.GRP` which records this information ( a simple group counter)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(temp)
DT[, index := .GRP, by = list(Dim1, Dim2)]
DT
#    Dim1 Dim2 Value index
# 1:    A  100    10     1
# 2:    A  100     2     1
# 3:    A  100     9     1
# 4:    A  100     4     1
# 5:    A  200     6     2
# 6:    A  200     1     2
# 7:    B  100     8     3
# 8:    B  200     7     4
```

Comment: What about data frame?

Answer (score 1):

Once the values in teh first argument have been partitioned, there is no way that ave "knows" what order they have been passed. You want a method that can look at changes in values. The `duplicated` function is generic and has a data.frame method that looks at multiple columns:

```
temp$indexSeqAlong <-  cumsum(!duplicated(temp[, 1:2]) )
temp

  Dim1 Dim2 Value indexSeqAlong
1    A  100     8             1
2    A  100     2             1
3    A  100     7             1
4    A  100     3             1
5    A  200     5             2
6    A  200     1             2
7    B  100     4             3
8    B  200    10             4
```

Is extensible to as many columns as you want.