# Adding index depend on variable in other column in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr

Here is my dataframe:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = "a", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I want to add an identification column that will act like index:

I mean that I want to add a column that will start from id = 1 and each time there is -1 to set it to be id = 2 and so on:
Expected:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1), b = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Using the solution from [R add index column to data frame based on row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870813/r-add-index-column-to-data-frame-based-on-row-values)
didn't work for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it like this. Just `cumsum` the logical vector created by `a==-1` and add one to the result of that:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(b = cumsum(a == -1) + 1)
```

or with Base R:

```
df1$b = cumsum(df1$a == -1) + 1
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
       a     b
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1
 2     1     1
 3    -1     2
 4     1     2
 5     1     2
 6     1     2
 7    -1     3
 8     1     3
 9     1     3
10     1     3
11     1     3
```

**Data:**

```
df1 = structure(list(a = c(1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = "a", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, `cumsum` will sum the -1 occurrences and  
and keep it same until another -1 comes in making idx be greated by 1? @useR

Comment: @steves Correct. `a==-1` creates a logical vector of `TRUE` when `a==-1` and `FALSE` when `a != -1`. When you apply `cumsum` to it, it starts with 0 because the first row is not `-1` and only adds one if it encounters a `TRUE`. Since you wanted `b` to start with 1, I added `1` to the vector so all values are increased by 1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

1. create a new helper column, which has the value `1` in the first row and every time there is a `-1`.
2. create the `index` column by using the `cumsum` function and delete the helper column

   ```
   library(dplyr)

   df %>%
     mutate(helper = ifelse(row_number()==1, 1, 
       ifelse(a == -1, 1, 0))) %>% 
     mutate(index = cumsum(helper)) %>%
     select(-helper)
   ```

Comment: BRAVO! SIMPLE, GENIUS STRAIGHT 2 THE POINT!